# How to share files between jobs

Tags: azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

Is it possible for two jobs to share files in multi-stage pipeline builds? `Publish` stage has `dotnet publish` job (single task) and `publish artifacts` job (single task). However, the output from `dotnet publish` doesn't seem to be available to `publish artifacts`.

Comment: Can you share your yaml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the each of the two jobs have a single task and the second task consumes the output of the first task. So why not run them under the same job.

You can refer to below yaml

```
  stages: 
  - stage: Publish
    displayName: 'Publish stage'
    jobs:
    - job: dotnetpublishartifacts
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'dotnet publish'
        inputs:
          command: publish
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
          arguments: '-o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          publishWebProjects: false 

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

If the two tasks have to be in separate jobs. And **the jobs run on the same agent**. Then you can try making the dotnet publish task output to an folder which will not be cleared by the next job(As the agent job will clear `build.artifactstagingdirectory` of the previous job),

In below example dotnet publish task output to `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\firtjobpublish`, this folder will not be cleared by the following job execution.

You may need to click on the **3dots** on the right to corner of your yaml pipeline edit page, click **triggers**, go to **YAML**, and in the **Get sources** section set **Clean** to **false**.
[image]

Below yaml is for example:

```
 jobs:
    - job: dotnetpublishartifacts
      pool: Default
      steps:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'dotnet publish'
        inputs: 
          command: publish
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
          arguments: '-o $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\firtjobpublish'
          publishWebProjects: false 

    - job: publishartifacts
      dependsOn: dotnetpublishartifacts
      pool: Default  
      steps:
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\firtjobpublish'
```

**Addtion**:
For sharing files between jobs, if **jobs run on different agents**, you can try adding a **publish artifacts task** in the first job to publish the artifacts to azure server. And in the following job add a **download artifacts task** to download the artifacts which is published by the previous job. This method is apparently not for your case.

Hope you find above helpful!

Comment: I like the visual separation and reporting of having them under different jobs. I'll give `download artifacts` a shot!

Comment: You can also run jobs in parallel, but not tasks

Comment: i don't have the setting "clean" in 2023